# In Java, How to test void method in Junit Mockito with assertion?

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

How to test void methods in Mockito with assertSame or assertEquals. I am able to do verify only. 
i am getting sonar or PMD rules violation -"JUnit tests should include assert() or fail()".
Below is my sample class with test class.

```
    @Service
    public class MyServiceImpl implements IService {

        @Autowired
        private IDyDBDAO dyDBDAO;

        @Override
        public void update() {
            dyDBDAO.save(getDetailData());
        }

        @Override
        public List<Detail> getCurrentDetail() {
            return getDetails(dyDBDAO.findAll());
        }

        private List<Detail> getDetails(Iterable<Detail> details) {
            ...blah...

        }

        private String getPlace(){
        Places p = Places.getPlace();//static

        return p == null? PlacesUtil.getName("DH"): p.getName;
        }
        private Detail getDetailData() {
            Detail d = new Detail();
            d.setName("blah");
        d.setDesc("fsdfsdfdsf");
        d.setPlace(getPlace());
            return d;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({Places.class, PlacesUtil.class})
    public class MyServiceImplTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

        @Mock
        private IDyDBDAO dyDBDAO;

        @Test
        public void testGetCurrentDetail() {
            given(dyDBDAO.findAll()).willReturn(getMockDetails());
            assertSame(myServiceImpl.getCurrentDetail().size(), 2);
        }

        @Test
        public void testUpdate() {
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Places.class);
            // first update  , second update -us-west-2 will update
            given(Places.getPlace()).willReturn(PlacesUtil.getName("UH"))
                    .willReturn(null);       
            myServiceImpl.syncStatus();
            // update again with DH
            myServiceImpl.syncStatus();
            verify(dyDBDAO, times(2)).save(any(Detail.class));
        // how to assert checking here
        }

        private Iterable<Detail> getMockDetails() {
            Detail d1 = new Detail();
            d1.setName("blah");
        d1.setDesc("fsdfsdfdsf");
        d1.setPlace("sdfsdf");

            Detail d2 = new Detail();
            d2.setName("blahblah1");
        d2.setDesc("e345345");
        d2.setPlace("8907j");

            List<Detail> listOfDetail = new ArrayList<>();
            listOfDetail.add(eps1);
            listOfDetail.add(eps2);
            return listOfDetail;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What method is void here? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: You can't. Then again the `update` method doesn't seem to have any significant logic to test anyway.

Comment: A `void` method that does anything meaningful will have to work through side-effects (on input parameters, persistent state). You need to assert the side-effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the value passed to the dao save method. Use mockito's ArgumentCaptor for that. Then assert on that value.
Something along these lines:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Detail> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Detail.class);
verify(dyDBDAO, times(2)).save(captor.capture());
Detail detail1 = captor.getValues().get(0)
assertEquals(expectedDetail, detail1)
```

Comment: How  to give expectedDetail here. how expectedDetail obj will create?

Comment: simply instantiate it, and set its property to whatever is expected by the test. Detail expectedDetail = new Detail();

Comment: Thank you. But if i create with new instance, how it will be same in assertEquals

Comment: That's the whole point of the test you're asserting the expected value created in the test and the actual value created (and then captured) by the class under test are the same

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your `void` method that needs to be tested is `update` in `MyServiceImpl`.

Firstly, you can verify if `dyDBDAO.save()` is called.

```
Mockito.verify(dyDBDAO).save(Mockito.anyList...);
```

Secondly, you can check the modified or created records in the database by retrieving them and comparing to the inputs from `getMockDetails`.